# MSTDC in SQL Server 2012 - Windows Server 2012 R2 with high availability

Tags: cluster, high-availability, failovercluster, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2012

We had implemented SQL Server High Availability on two physical servers over the VPN network.
SQL Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2.

It was noted that, Distributed Transaction was working perfectly with NODE1 and NODE2 switched on and also NODE1 ON and NODE2 OFF.

We tested, failover switching off NODE1 and NODE2 one at a time and vice versa.

It was experienced that, MSDTC was not working after the failover.

It was noted in the below link also,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366279.aspx

But, in the Failover cluster manager I could spot  - SQL Server MSDTC role which is available for addition. Would that role added resolve the issue? Or is it necessary that we need to roll back to Normal Failover cluster installation with SAN storage for this to take place?

Another, features noted was, when both the nodes were switched on NODE2 was available in read-only mode. Is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. It is impossible to implement MSDTC services while using SQL Server 2012/2012R2/2014, high availability platforms. You will not able to add, MSDTC Services to your Cluster services role.

I reverted the whole system to classical Clustring services - SQLNODE1,SQLNODE2,SAN Drive [we installed Buffallo Tera Byte solution]. Installation was done directly on the SAN Drive.

Please chose your platform, SAN Solution and interlocks based on your requirement and future integrations or uses in mind.